Adding an AC outlet under my kitchen sink for RO system
I’m looking to add an outlet here under my kitchen sink for a tankless RO system. The system itself takes an AC outlet which I don’t currently have under my sink. Is it possible to add a normal outlet off of this box on the wall? The top white cord is coming from a GFCI outlet above my countertop. It’s currently powering my dishwasher and disposal. The RO system says it needs a 120-240v outlet.
I will say that the space inside the box is pretty tight now that both the disposal and the dishwasher are in there. I’m assuming I’d need a bigger box to fit an outlet there.
Updated Findings (Sept 6 24):
I've been trying to add comments on my post here, but I created this question as a guest, and then created this user (or maybe I had another account on stackoverflow or something), anyway, thought I'd add a little more context here as I took a look at my main box and the amperage on both of my disposal and dishwasher.
The circuit that both my dishwasher and disposal are on, is a 20A circuit. The dishwasher says a total amperage of 9.6A and my disposal says a total amperage of 9.5A. Based on the answer below, it seems like I've maxed out this circuit and should not try to add any outlet to this same circuit.
Since I don't have enough rep on this stackexchange I can't comment to some of you who have left comments, but in terms of what these wires are connected to in the picture, I can give a little more context there.
The top white cable is connected to a switch above the sink, which has a single GFCI outlet just below it in the same box. The bottom metal casing runs into the drywall and I'm unsure where exactly that leads to. The left metal casing is my dishwasher (hardwired) and the right metal casing runs to my disposal (also hardwired). Hopefully that adds a little more context to the situation.


missing a picture

What do you mean by, "The RO system says it takes a 120-240V outlet."?  Does the RO require only 120 V or does it require 240 V (and maybe120 V as well)?

You probably need to determine where each of those cables goes, and what they're connected to.

You can generally have as many receptacles as you want on a circuit, with however much stuff you want to have plugged in to those receptacles. However, you have to keep in mind the total power requirements. A typical kitchen circuit will be 20A but though some older circuits are only 15A. A dishwasher might use only a few amps when running but go to 10A or more when heating water or drying. A disposal will typically pull several amps when running, but only for a few seconds at a time. RO system? No idea. But with plug-in appliances the power management is all on you.
On the other hand, if you have hardwired devices - as I have with my dishwasher and disposal - you have to follow certain rules. Basically you can't put more hardwired stuff on a circuit than the capacity of the circuit, with an additional catch that continuous loads (I believe more than 3 hours have to be derated to 80%).
But there is one more catch: If you have hardwired loads > 50% of circuit capacity then you can't have any regular receptacles for plug-in devices on the same circuit. For example, if your hardwired dishwasher can use up to 11A then you can't have any other receptacles on a 20A circuit, but you could have an 8A disposal. On the other hand, if the dishwasher is plug/cord connected then you can have multiple receptacles and you are responsible for not overloading the circuit.
But wait, you say, if I have a circuit breaker isn't that a guarantee I'll never be able to overload the circuit? Not exactly. Particularly at edge situations - e.g., between 20A and 25A on a 20A circuit the breaker may take a long time to trip (see "trip curve"). That is OK once in a while but not good to do that on a regular basis.
